# How to see what is returned ? (true / false )

Tags: android, debugging, cursor

It might sound stupid but seriously, I am looking for an error, from what I read on internet I should try to read what has been returned (in my case "cursor.moveToFirst()", true or false) but I can't find where to see this. No message in my app of course, nothing in the logcat, so where is it ?
Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try

```
boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();

Context context = getApplicationContext(); 
int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

Toast.makeText(context, "debug:" + result , duration).show();
```

it'll then pop up on your device.

or you can try

```
boolean result = cursor.moveToFirst();
Log.d("TESTING", "debug:" +result);
```

then filter the LogCat with `"TESTING"`

Comment: Warning: local variable 'text' was never used.

Comment: Perfect, the first one (with the toast) works fine for me, I get my result. On the other hand, I didn't get anything in the logcat with the second one, but maybe I used it in a wrong way. Anyway, thanks, get my result now !

Comment: @Phalanx, maybe you selected to view at a different log level for the adb logs -(there's Log.i, Log.d, Log.w, Log.e, etc)